# python string processing, when directly put word is ok when b[1] is not

Tags: string, python-3.x, split, cpu-word, identify

I want to judge if all words in a string are proper English words.
I am using a function to check it:

```
is_word_english(word: str)
```

Returns a boolean value

The function can only process a word so I use `split()`to take out spaces between words. 
Here is an example:

```
a = ('Apple Banana')
b = a.split() 
b
['Apple', 'Banana']
b[1]
'Banana'
is_word_english(b[1])
False
is_word_english('banana')
True
```

Comment: Try `is_word_english(b[1].lower())`. Your `is_word_english` function is likely case-sensitive.

Comment: as @blhsing `is_word_english(b[1].lower())`this should work since what you do is make sure all words are on lowercase. It will, however, not work for some words that require capital letters (example English, Spanish, .. or UN .. )

Comment: Remmember that python is case sensitive. Banana is not equal to banana.

Answer (score 0):

If the output for `banana` and `Banana` differs it means `is_word_english` is case-sensitive and you'll have to use `str.lower` first:

```
a = ('Apple Banana')
words = a.split()
lower_words = map(str.lower, words) # this part is missing in your code?
is_all_english = all(map(is_word_english, lower_words))
```

If `is_word_english` handles ONLY lowercase words (seems reasonable) you can wrap it for convenience:

```
def is_word_english_ci(word):
    return is_word_english(word.lower())
```